# "Bipartitely independent" sets in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Given a graph $G = (V,E)$, an independent set (also called a stable set sometimes) is a subset $I \subseteq V$ such that there are no edges between any two vertices in $I$. In other words, the induced subgraph $G[I]$ has no edges.

I am interested in a related notion. I have two disjoint subsets $I,J \subseteq V$ such that there are no edges between $I$ and $J$. In other words, the bipartite subgraph $G[I,J]$ (this is less standard, but existing notation) has no edges. I'm not assuming $G$ itself is bipartite.

(A lot of the time, we want to find the largest independent set in $G$. For me, the analogous problem is finding two sets $I$ and $J$ such as above which maximize $\min\{|I|,|J|\}$.)

Is there a word for such sets $I$ and $J$ that are "bipartitely independent"?

Comment: I know this is old, but look up "bipartite holes" or "bi-independence number"...see here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.08423.pdf or here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00888

Comment: It's old, but as it happens we *are* still revising that same paper, so maybe I'll get the chance to use this terminology :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google suggests that that's called a *$2$-anticoloring*, and finding an example with prescribed $|I|$ and $|J|$ is the *black-and-white coloring problem*.

Comment: Nice find! I'd have preferred something that didn't involve coloring vertices, but in the likely event that nobody has any suggestions like that, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is useful to you, but the bipartite graph $G[I,J]$ has no edges if and only if $S = V - I - J$ is a separating vertex set. In this case $(I + S, J + S)$ is what is sometimes called an $|S|$-separator of $G$. Your problem could be solved by finding, for each $0 \leq k \leq |V|$, a $k$-separator $(A,B)$ which maximizes $\min\{|A|,|B|\}$. Of course this is also hard, even for $k = 0$.